# Handling "this" correctly

Tags: javascript

I had a JS class (as a requirejs module) which looked like this:

```
define(function () {
    function MyClass() { };
    MyClass.prototype.getPrefix = function(){
        return 'myclass.'
    };
    MyClass.prototype.setKey = function (key, value) {
        var prefix = this.getPrefix();
        localStorage.setItem(prefix+key, value);
    };
    MyClass.prototype.getKey = function (key) {
        var prefix = this.getPrefix();
        return localStorage.getItem(prefix+key);
    };  
    return MyClass;
});
```

Then I added another function and wanted to have my code organized better by putting some functions under a namespace, so I changed to:

```
define(function () {
    function MyClass() { }; 
    MyClass.prototype.getPrefix = function(){
        return 'myclass.'
    };
    MyClass.prototype.storage = {
        setKey: function (key, value) {
            var prefix = this.getPrefix(); //OOPS
            localStorage.setItem(prefix+key, value);
        },
        getKey: function (key) {
            var prefix = this.getPrefix(); //OOPS
            return localStorage.getItem(prefix+key);
        }
    };  
    return MyClass;
});
```

But this causes problems because "this" when calling `this.getPrefix()` has changed.

What would be the best\nicest way to handle it and succesfully call getPrefix from within the functions under the `storage`?

Answer (score 2):

Either you define another "class" for storage and compose with MyClass (MyClass HAS an instance of MyStorage ) , or you refactor MyClass into something like :

```
MyClass.prototype.setStorageKey= function (key, value) {...}

MyClass.prototype.getStorageKey= function (key) {...}
```

Because if you go down the path you chosed you'll get many unexpected side-effects. In your code , this will refer to storage and not an instance of MyClass.